# copying an array of object and ordering some items

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of object and I want to copy that array of object to another array while modifying some items, like copying `id` only by ascending order and copying only the value of trophies of basketball to trophies. How to do it?

```
const item = [{
                "id": 33,
                "name": "John"
                "trophies": {
                        "basketball" : 2,
                        "baseball" : 5
                           },
                 "profile": "profile/212"
               }
              {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "Michael"
                "trophies": {
                        "basketball" : 6,
                        "baseball" : 7
                           },
                "profile": "profile/341"
               }
            ]
```

I want the above array of object after copying to look something like

```
const item2 = [{
                "id": 12,
                "name": "Michael"
                "trophies": 6,
                "profile": "http://collegeprofile.com/profile/341"
               },
               
              {
                "id": 33,
                "name": "John"
                "trophies": 2,
                "profile": "http://collegeprofile.com/profile/212"
               }
            ]
```

Answer (score 2):

- You can sort by id ascending order using `Array.prototype.sort`
- And map `basketball` value to `trophies` using `Array.prototype.map`.

```js
const item = [{
  "id": 33,
  "name": "John",
  "trophies": {
    "basketball": 2,
    "baseball": 5
  },
  "profile": "profile/212"
}, {
  "id": 12,
  "name": "Michael",
  "trophies": {
    "basketball": 6,
    "baseball": 7
  },
  "profile": "profile/341"
}];

const output = item.sort((a, b) => (a.id - b.id)).map((item) => ({
  ...item,
  trophies: item.trophies.basketball,
  profile: "http://collegeprofile.com/" + item.profile
}));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: I'd suggest `(a.id - b.id)` instead of `(a.id > b.id)`.

Comment: @Derek.W  Thanks for your answer. also how would I modify that profile to a profile link?